# Check Max Thunderbolt 3 Speed

Tags: external-display, bandwidth, speed, thunderbolt, cuda

How do I check the bandwidth (max Gbps) of my Thunderbolt 3 port? I'm trying to see if it can handle supporting 4 additional monitors with my Wavlink docking station (so that I can get either 1080p/1440p/2160p monitors at 60Hz). Can I use Cuda?